# html export option to NOT compress multiple spaces in emacs org mode

Tags: emacs, export, org-mode

While doing html-export in org-mode, multiple spaces are compressed to a single space. Is there a way to change this default behaviour. (I do not wish to replace extra spaces with nbsp)

Comment: What context are you trying to preserve the spaces in?  Certain types of blocks in Org maintain spacing so those might be the solution, but it would depend just what sort of content you're trying to keep with the additional spaces left in.

Answer (score 3):

I just tested this, and org-mode does not appear to delete spaces from the content when using `org-export-as-html`.

Web browsers, of course, *do* collapse white-space when rendering HTML.

I suggest you look into the [`white-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#white-space-prop) CSS property (the `pre-wrap` value is probably what you want), along with Org Mode's support for CSS in exported HTML:
<kbd>M-:</kbd> `(info "(org) CSS support")` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: How do you implement a CSS value in Orgmode? I can't deduce it from the manual, sadly. My workaround so far is to put `#+HTML: <pre>` and `#+HTML: </pre>` around the document.